# how to rerun init state of widget from out side of class in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout, rebuild

I want to rerun init State of Widget when user click on button(which is in other widget) of App.

I tried following code but not worked:

```
onPressed:(){
ExampleWidget();
}
```

**Explanation:**
I want to rerun Widget when user click on a button. That button is defined in other widget of the app The Example Code is Below:

```
class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
const ExampleWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<ExampleWidget> createState() => ExampleWidgetState();
 }

class ExampleWidgetState extends State<ExampleWidget> {

Code between this Brackets

}
```

I want to rerun this Widget. I am Try Following Method:

```
class OtherWidget extends StatelessWidget {


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
 onPressed:() {  ExampleWidget()  }
,child:Icon(Icons.delete)
 ,),),}
```

If you know the answer of this question the answer  this question..

Comment: Why do you declare the function inside init state?

Comment: I didn't declare it in initState i only run it + I also added a setState command in init State so that is why running init state is crucial.

Comment: So you can just run the function and call setState in your onPressed? Sorry, I do not see the necessity to run initState again

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `FutureBuilder` to call the function which is in `init` State. It can call the function each time when button is pressed. Check [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).